# Is there an advantage to selecting MAIN with other selectors?

Tags: css, html

In HTML5, the `main` element is defined to mean "the main content of the `body` of a document or application" [*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) , that "Authors must not include more than one `main` element in a document," [*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element)  and that "Authors must not include the `main` element as a descendant of an `article`, `aside`, `footer`, `header` or `nav` element." [*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element)

This, to me, means that it's intended for all `main` element to always match `body > main:only-of-type { }`. However, when writing CSS, it's my instinct to specify something like `body > main { }`. **Will `main { }` always do the job without any other selector, or should its parent or some other attribute be selected as well?**

> * As according to [Section 4.5.14 of HTML5 W3C Candidate Recommendation, as published on 6 August 2013](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element)

Comment: I don't think you should select elements like main at all. I'd suggest using a class on it and select this. What else do you need? Apart from that, this question is pretty opinion based.

Comment: I intend to add padding to the body's main content, but not its header, footer, etc. This seemed to be the most semantic way to do so.

Comment: Why you don't use `<main class="site-content">` and `.site-content { padding: 20px; }`? If you don't want to use classes, selecting `main` is just fine, because there should be only one.

Comment: Ther is no "semantic" ways here to do that other than `main {}` there is no semantic jus specificity check my answer

Comment: @kleinfreund Several reasons. One is that I don't want to accidentally affect the main element by changing some class that applies to many elements. Another is that I want all main elements to be given some padding to keep the text and other visual elements away from the edges of the viewport. Also, since I'm not going to be the only one using this CSS, I don't want someone applying `.site-content` to every element they think needs some extra padding.

Comment: @Danko I mean to keep the HTML semantic. This is the point of HTML and the `main` element in particular. This means using HTML _only_ for the structure, and to _not_ change your HTML code to change the look of the page, but just the layout. This is one reason why we don't use `table`s to lay out webpages anymore

Comment: Html semantic ... is just different from CSS I point you it again **Semantic in CSS is like specificity** just do `main {}` with specificity you get the answer of *Is there an advantage to selecting MAIN with other selectors?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is just about [Specificity](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/)<sup>Cascade</sup>, of course if you must have just one `main` element wil be enough to style it with some  like:

```
main {
  background:red
}
```

So you don't need to do more than that. But there can be some cases where other values can be applied to obtain more [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)<sup>MDN</sup>. For example you want an specific page to have another background color so you can:

- Assign a classname to `main` :

  ```
  <main class="change">

  main.change {
    background:blue;
  }
  ```
- Or one class on his parent `body` :

  ```
  body.change  main {
    background:blue;
  }
  ```

On both cases you gain more relevance than just set `main`.